# How to pass text into component in React-Native? (Android)

Tags: android, reactjs, function, react-native, mobile

I'm calling the following function

```
const LevelCard = (level) => {
    const currLevel = level;
    console.log(currLevel)
    return (
        <View style={{
            flex: 1,
            width: 400,
            alignItems: 'center', 
            justifyContent: 'center'
        }}>
        <CategoryButton
            title='Text should go here'
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate('')}
        />
        </View>
    );
}
```

from another component

```
function CallFunction() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.categories}>
        <ScrollView horizontal={true} style={styles.scrollView}>
          <View>

            <LevelCard 
                level="This is the text I want to pass"
            />

          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
}
```

but I can't figure out how to actually get the text from 'level' to show up anywhere in the react-native components. The console.log statements work correctly outside of it however.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i recomend you to take a look at props in react, in a general way of explaining it, you can think of props like this: "props are to components what arguments are to functions". Right now you are correctly passing the text to your LevelCard Component but you are not retrieving it correctly, props are passed as an object so you have to destructure it from the receiving component:

```
const LevelCard = ({ level }) => { // <--- Notice this line
  const currLevel = level;
  console.log(currLevel)
  return (
    <View style={{
        flex: 1,
        width: 400,
        alignItems: 'center', 
        justifyContent: 'center'
    }}>
    <CategoryButton
        title={level} {/* then use it like this*/}
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('')}
    />
    </View>
  );

}
```

Comment: Thanks. Although adding the curly braces didn't do anything, your advice was sound. passing props and doing title = {props.level} allowed me to pinpoint the correct data

Comment: oh yeah wait, i updated my answer forgot to point how to use it

Comment: but you are right u also can do that props.level or whatever your prop name is